# Can I search and replace colours in a CSS file when a page loads?

Tags: php, css

What I want to do is search for all instances of a particular colour within a CSS document, identified by its hex value, and replace all those instances with a new hex value. Then, *after* the colours have been changed, the CSS is applied to the page.

Really, a CSS document is just a text file, so surely there's a way to catch it before it is served to the browser and do some text based search and replace. Look for a particular HEX code and replace all instances with another.

How could that be done?

Comment: I don't think it's possible and I don't see any point to do that. Why don't you do it in PHP or create CSS with values you want?

Comment: can you change the content of any file which is separate from the page. you can modify the inline/internal content only

Comment: if i am not geting it wrong, you want to change the css file right ? if you are going to change css then it will change permanently , you should need to make main css file and then make another for main colors of the page. after this you will need a 3rd css file which will replace the 2nd css file which contains colors, just replace colors files with your new file.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
function changeColor(oldColor, newColor) {
   var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

   Array.prototype.forEach.call(all, function(element){
     if (element.style.background === oldColor) {
       element.style.background = newColor;
     }
   })  
}
```

This way you're looping over each element on the page, checking if it has the old color, and then if so, changing it to the new color.

Comment: You beat me to it, Josh!

Comment: Thank you for this response. However, I need a way that can search and replace based on the colour, not on a designated class or id.

Comment: @DaveMG Just changed the answer so that you can check every element on the page instead.

Comment: Thank you for that code. Sorry, I realize now my question was a bit misleading because of the example. The colours I need to change aren't always going to be a background. They might be anything that cna take a colour, like border, text colours, shadows...

Comment: @DaveMG just add additional if statements into that function for those. Unfortunately you cannot select elements on the page strictly select by color.

Answer (score 1):

First there are some errors in your code.

I have creaeted a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Uet9A/)**

```
    function changeColor(color) {
   var a =  document.getElementById('coloredThing');
   a.style.background = color;
}
```